# I can't seem to align in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm struggling to get the objects to align seperatly across the top bar I've pus-do created in app

my code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DnD"
             x:Class="DnD.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <FlexLayout Grid.Row="0"
                        BackgroundColor="Blue"
                        Direction="Row">
                <Image WidthRequest="25" Source="img/Back.png"  HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Tapped="OnTapBackBTN"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Label HeightRequest="25" Text="Menu Title" HorizontalOptions="Center">

                </Label>
                <Image WidthRequest="25" Source="img/Bars.png" HorizontalOptions="End">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Tapped="OnTapMenuBTN" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </FlexLayout>

            <ScrollView Grid.Row="1"
                        BackgroundColor="Red">

            </ScrollView>

            <RelativeLayout Grid.Row="2"
                         BackgroundColor="Green">

            </RelativeLayout>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
    <!--<ContentPage.BackgroundColor></ContentPage.BackgroundColor>-->

</ContentPage>
```

[As you can see it all force left in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuPHE.png)

I tried HorizontalAlignment that I seen but is a unrecognized property.

Is there something like CSS used in HTML or something to get my desired effect in XAML

Comment: get rid of the FlexLayout and place your three elements in the appropriate column of your Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to specify the content alignment of your FlexLayout, you need to set the JustifyContent property.

```
<FlexLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    Direction="Row"
                    JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
```

However in terms of layout performance, you'd be better off using a Grid with three columns, as Jason mentioned yesterday.

My personal opinion however is that it seems you are putting a lot of effort into trying to implement a functionality that xamarin.forms would give you out of the box, if you  used a MasterDetailPage with a NavigationPage sitting in the Detail View.

Comment: Well this is a first for me with Xarmin, the only other markup langue i use is HTML and then i use CSS to get the results I want. I'll take a look into MasterDeatailPage.